# react native: floating button in with bottom Navigation?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, expo

I'm working on a project were I have to mix bottom navigation with a circular button in the middle of two bottom tab navigation in react native

here's an Image to describe how I want it to look like:

[image]

my code so far:

```
const { Navigator, Screen } = createBottomTabNavigator<WalletBottomTabNavigatorParamList>();

const BottomTabBar = ({ navigation, state, referralRequest }: any) => (
  <BottomNavigation
    selectedIndex={state.index}
    onSelect={(index) => navigation.navigate(state.routeNames[index])}
    style={{ display: (state.routeNames[state.index]) === "AddReferral" ? 'none' : 'flex' }}
  >
    <BottomNavigationTab
      title={i18n.t("bottomNavigation:requests")}
      icon={IconComponent(evaIcons.team, Colors.black900)}
    />
    <BottomNavigationTab
      title={i18n.t("bottomNavigation:sentRequest")}
      icon={IconComponent(evaIcons.plus, Colors.black900)}
    />
  </BottomNavigation>
);


export const WalletBottomTabNavigator = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();


  return (
    <Navigator
      backBehavior="history"
      initialRouteName={'Home'}
      tabBar={(props) => <BottomTabBar {...props}/>}
    >
      <Screen name='Transactions' component={WalletScreen} options={{
        headerTitle: "",
        headerLeft: () => <HeaderRight />,
        headerRight: () => <ProductsButton />,
        title: i18n.t("bottomNavigation:team"),
      }} />
      {/* <Screen name="AddReferral" component={AddNewReferralScreen} options={{
        headerShown: false,
      }}
      /> */}
      <Screen name="Transfer" component={InvitationsScreen} options={{
        headerTitle: "",
        headerLeft: () => <HeaderRight />,
        headerRight: () => <ProductsButton />,
        title: i18n.t("bottomNavigation:requests"),
      }} />
    </Navigator>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try to use [custom tab bar](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/#tabbar)**

```
    import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

function MyTabBar({ state, descriptors, navigation }) {
  return (
////////////////////////////// add next 2 views and don't forget to close first tag at bottom
<View >
     <View
        style={{
          width: 50,
          height: 50,
          borderRadius: 50,
          backgroundColor: "yellow",
          position: "absolute",
          top: -25,
     
        }}
      ></View>
////////////////////////////
    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
      {state.routes.map((route, index) => {
        const { options } = descriptors[route.key];
        const label =
          options.tabBarLabel !== undefined
            ? options.tabBarLabel
            : options.title !== undefined
            ? options.title
            : route.name;

        const isFocused = state.index === index;

        const onPress = () => {
          const event = navigation.emit({
            type: 'tabPress',
            target: route.key,
            canPreventDefault: true,
          });

          if (!isFocused && !event.defaultPrevented) {
            // The `merge: true` option makes sure that the params inside the tab screen are preserved
            navigation.navigate({ name: route.name, merge: true });
          }
        };

        const onLongPress = () => {
          navigation.emit({
            type: 'tabLongPress',
            target: route.key,
          });
        };

        return (
          <TouchableOpacity
            accessibilityRole="button"
            accessibilityState={isFocused ? { selected: true } : {}}
            accessibilityLabel={options.tabBarAccessibilityLabel}
            testID={options.tabBarTestID}
            onPress={onPress}
            onLongPress={onLongPress}
            style={{ flex: 1 }}
          >
            <Text style={{ color: isFocused ? '#673ab7' : '#222' }}>
              {label}
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        );
      })}
    </View>
 </View> /////////////////// close first tag
  );
}

// ...

<Tab.Navigator tabBar={props => <MyTabBar {...props} />}>
  {...}
</Tab.Navigator>
```

[image]